# NSClassFromString Doesn't work for Optional Values

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

NSClassFromString does not work when working with optionals:

```
var t = NSClassFromString("Swift.Optional<MyModule.MyClass>")
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: NSClassFromString takes a class as input and not string. Try `NSClassFromString(MyModule.MyClass.Self)

Comment: @NaveenPrasadR `NSClassFromString` is `Class` _from_ `String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct! `NSClassFromString` does not work with optionals as optionals are not classes. `Optional` is actually a generic enum, containing cases `.None` (aka `nil`) and `.Some(actualValue)`. I'm afraid `NSClassFromString` is not meant to work with optionals.

That doesn't stop you, however, from writing/reading `MyModule.MyClass` directly and dealing with the creation of an optional yourself. For example:

```
var t = NSClassFromString("MyModule.MyClass")
var newObject = whateverYouWereGoingToDoWithT(t)
var optionalVersion = Optional(newObject)
```